# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime (Access DB and VB)

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, ms-access-2016

I have an issue which is adding data to Microsoft Access Database and it got an error message 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'. I have tried searching for an answer in here and several other websites but I still get the error. Please help me on this issue and thanks.

My Code:

```
With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAILS (ID, OrderNo, ProductDate, TimeStart, TimeEnd) VALUES (@ID, @OrderNo, @ProductDate, @TimeStart, @TimeEnd)"

            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ID", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 255, Me.ID_tb.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@OrderNo", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 255, Me.orderno_tb.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ProductDate", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char, 255, Me.productdate_tb.TextMaskFormat))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@TimeStart", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.DBDate, Me.tstat_tb.TextMaskFormat))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@TimeEnd", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.DBTime, Me.tend_tb.TextMaskFormat))

            cm.Parameters("@ID").Value = Me.ID_tb.Text
            cm.Parameters("@OrderNo").Value = Me.orderno_tb.Text
            cm.Parameters("@ProductDate").Value = DateTime.Parse(Me.productdate_tb.TextMaskFormat)
            cm.Parameters("@TimeStart").Value = DateTime.Parse(Me.tstat_tb.TextMaskFormat)
            cm.Parameters("@TimeEnd").Value = DateTime.Parse(tend_tb.TextMaskFormat)

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Format of my Product Date, Time Start and Time End in Access Database and in Form (Masked TextBox):

> Product Date = dd-MMM-yy
>   Time Start = hh:mm
>   Time End = hh:mm

FYI, I also have tried using `cm.Parameters("@ProductDate").Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Me.productdate_tb.TextMaskFormat, "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but it didn't work. I'm not sure if I did it right or wrong.

Comment: Have you checked to see what date is returned from the text boxes? Even with a `Mask` the user can still type in an invalid date. It will fit the mask… but the date will be bad. Example: 33/33/3333 is valid for the mask, but will fail when parsed.

Comment: Firstly, I'm not sure why the cause should be a mystery. The error message says that the value provided wasn't recognised as a valid DateTime so it should be obvious that the value provided was not valid.  Have you looked at what that value is?  You haven't told us so it would appear that you don't see how important that value is.  You haven't even told us which of the three values it is.  Are you sure that it's the date and not the times?

Comment: Secondly, why use a `MaskedTextBox` for dates and times when you can use a `DateTimePicker`?  It would handle both the validation and the conversion implicitly.

Comment: Do you *really* want to pass the `TextMaskFormat` to the DB? Wouldn't it be more useful to pass the value obtained by appropriately parsing the text of the texbox?

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a DateTimePicker, which would be the best solution, you can check the input with the IsDate(StringToTest) function.
If the input is NOT a valid date, you get a False, so you can address the user to properly fill up the field.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I have tried to study the coding in different ways and I have realized that I have made a huge mistake in the coding. Thank you for taking time to reply my question and thank you for the comments, it make me rethink and study back the coding. Below is the updated coding and I'm able to insert data to Access without any error. Feel free to point out if there is still a mistake in my coding because I still need to learn about it. This is not the code that I created by myself, I use the code from this [website](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/writeToAccessTable.htm) and only change a few that suitable with what I needed.

```
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL ([ID],[OrderNo],[ProductDate],[TimeStart],[TimeEnd]) VALUES (@ID, @OrderNo, @ProductDate, @TimeStart, @TimeEnd)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ID", CType(ID_tb.Text, Integer)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@OrderNo", CType(ordernum_tb.Text, Integer)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ProductDate", CType(productdate_tb.Text, Date)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TimeStart", CType(tstat_tb.Text, Date)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TimeEnd", CType(tend_tb.Text, Date)))
```

Comment: A few things to think about. Consider using DateTime.Parse (or DataTime.TryParse). 
I would also recommend avoiding inline SQL, go for a Stored Procedure instead. We have a lot of inline SQL in our old apps which makes it a nightmare to change.